# Understanding the steps of Karmarkar's algorithm

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, algorithms, linear-programming, numerical-optimization

I am working through Karmarkar's seminal paper [0] and came across something I didn't quite understand. In section 2.3, *Description of the Algorithm*, he explains how to calculate the next point. The point $\mathbf{x^{(k)}} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ that is put into  $\phi$ has to be a feasible point, i.e., A$\mathbf{x}^{(k)}=0$. The matrix $D$ is a diagonal matrix with the $\mathbf{x_i}^{(k)}$ on the diagonal. Now,

\begin{align*}AD=\begin{pmatrix}A_1 \mathbf{x}_1^{(k)}\dots A_n \mathbf{x}_n^{(k)} \end{pmatrix}\end{align*}

where $A_i$ is the $i$th column of $A$. We know that the sum of these components is $0$.

The matrix $B$ is the matrix $AD$ with a row of $1$'s at the bottom. Now, in the algorithm it says that

$$\mbox{Ker} B \subseteq \Sigma = \left\{ \mathbf{x} \mid \sum_i x_i=1 \right\}$$

But $\mbox{Ker} B = \vec{0}$, because the last row of $B$ consists of ones. Am I not seeing something here?

---

[0] Narendra Karmarkar, [A new polynomial-time algorithm for linear programming](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02579150), Combinatorica, Volume 4, Issue 4, December 1984.

Comment: The link is here: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.136.1990&rep=rep1&type=pdf. Cannot find DOI.